# Probability of choosing two aces

Tags: probability

I've had this question in my workbook which I can't understand. Basically the question is based on relative frequency.The question goes along the lines of

> Five cards (ace, king, queen, jack and 10) are placed face down on a table. One card is selected at random and replaced. A second card is then selected at random. This experiment is repeated 200 times.
>
> What is the probability of selecting 2 aces?

The wording is what I mess up on, if it were more straight forward I would probably understand it a bit better.

Comment: Do you mean: What is the probability that after 200 rounds, there are (at least?) two aces on table? Anyway, sounds like a pretty complicated question ... Perhaps you could think of a finite-state machine where you are only concerned with the number of aces on the table. We start with 1 and we make some random changes ... And then we want the probability that after 200 rounds the number is (at least) 2. My Markov chain sense is tingling! Luckily, we only have 5 states, because the numer of aces is either 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4. Then we need to calculate the transition probabilities ...

Comment: @MattiP. Yes.Selecting 2 aces after 200 rounds.

Comment: The question sounds to me like it just asks for the probability of drawing two Aces in succession $(1/25)$. I don't understand what, if anything, the $200$ times has to do with anything.

Comment: I feel like even if it was nicely phrased this wouldn't be a very good question any way, you may want to wonder about the following : suppose you play an infinite amont of time, what is the expected time before you get an ace and then a king in a row, what is the expected time before you get two aces in a row, how do they compare. You can also think about three cards, if I tell you that I bet on a king, a queen and ace in a row, what can you bet to beat me on average ?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes! you're right i might have oversimplified the question a bit, but then again as i mentioned the wording in these problems are pretty weird.Also mind elaborating how you got 1/25? Im really dumb.Thanks

Comment: @P.Quinton i have no clue bro

Comment: Since the trials are done with replacement, you could use the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: @Xardous The probability of drawing the Ace out of $5$ cards is $1/5$.  Drawing a second time is independent and has the same probability so, the combined probability is $\frac15\cdot\frac15$.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks again :)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I Will look into that. thanks.

Comment: I agree that the question is as written poorly worded.  It would make sense to me that each "experiment" consists of two drawings with replacement of a card from your collection.  It mentions that the experiment is then repeated several times.  I would imagine the question of "the probability of drawing two aces" they are after here is the probability that in a specific iteration of the experiment that both of the two cards drawn are aces.  I would further imagine that there are many more questions that can/should follow which make use of the fact that the experiment is repeated.

Comment: For example, the next thing that might be asked is "What is the expected number of the 200 trials of the experiment that we see two aces?"  and then "What is the variance on the number of trials of the experiment that we see two aces" etc... I strongly suspect that these or similar questions ought to have appeared in the original printing of the problem which you neglected to include in  your post here which caused unnecessary confusion to the people attempting to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of choosing an ace each time is 1/5.  The probability of choosing the ace two times in a row (one "experiment") is 1/25.    The probability that you will NOT choose two aces in one "experiment" is 24/25.  The probability that you will NOT choose two aces in any of 200 "experiments" is (24/25)^200 and the probability you WILL choose two aces at least once in the 200 "experiments" is 1- (24/25)^200.  And, just to include all possible interpretations, the probability of choosing two aces in **all** 200 "experiments" is (1/25)^200.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually quite ambiguous. Here are three possible interpretations:

> Five cards (ace, king, queen, jack and 10) are placed face down on a table. One card is selected at random and replaced. A second card is then selected at random. This experiment is repeated 200 times. What is the probability of selecting at least 2 aces?

It is $1$ minus the probability of selecting no aces or exactly one ace. So, the answer is $1 - (\frac{4}{5})^{199}(\frac{4}{5} + \frac{200}{5}) = \frac{5^{200} - 4^{200}\times 3 \times 17}{5^200}$

> Five cards (ace, king, queen, jack and 10) are placed face down on a table. One card is selected at random and replaced. A second card is then selected at random. This experiment is repeated 200 times. What is the probability of selecting exactly 2 aces?

The answer here is $C_{200}^2 (\frac{1}{5})^2 (\frac{4}{5})^{198} = \frac{2^{398} \times 3 \times 67}{5^{198}}$

> Five cards (ace, king, queen, jack and 10) are placed face down on a table. One card is selected at random and replaced. A second card is then selected at random. This experiment is repeated 200 times. What is the probability of selecting 2 aces in a row?

It is $1$ minus the probability of not selecting two aces in a row. Let's describe $P_A(n)$ the probability that there were no two aces in a row in the first $n$ experiments and that the $n$-th experiment is an ace. Let's describe $P_B(n)$ the probability that there were no two aces in a row in the first $n$ experiments and that the $n$-th experiment is not an ace. Then we have:

$$P_A(n + 1) = \frac{1}{5}P_B(n)$$
$$P_B(n + 1) = \frac{4}{5}(P_A(n) + P_B(n))$$

Now suppose $P(n) = P_A(n) + P_B(n)$. Then $$P(n) = \frac{4}{5}P(n - 1) + \frac{4}{25}P(n - 2)$$. Knowing, that $$P(0) = P(1) = 1$$ we can solve this recurrence as $$P(n) = (\frac{4}{5})^n\frac{(5\sqrt{2} + 1)(1 + \sqrt{2})^n + (5\sqrt{2} - 1)(1 - \sqrt{2})^n}{10 \sqrt{2}}$$

From that we can conclude that the answer is:

$$1 - (\frac{4}{5})^{200}\frac{(5\sqrt{2} + 1)(1 + \sqrt{2})^{200} + (5\sqrt{2} - 1)(1 - \sqrt{2})^{200}}{10 \sqrt{2}}$$